# php not executing function on submit button pressed in html

Tags: php, html

So I got this code and I'm still learning and I don't know what might the problem be, and a question is it unsafe to do this way?

```
<?php
    print_form();
    if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){
        process_form();
    }
    function process_form(){
        switch($_POST){
            case "addition":
                print $_POST['operand1'] + $_POST['operand2'];
                break;
            case "subtraction":

                break;
            case "multiplication":

                break;
            case "division":

        }
    }
    function print_form(){
        print <<<HTML
            <html>
                <head><title>Learning Php</title></head>

                <body>
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        Operand 1: <input type="text" name="operand1"><br>
                        Operand 2: <input type="text" name="operand2"><br>
                        <select name="operation">
                            <option value="addition"> Addition </option>
                            <option value="subtraction"> Subtraction </option>
                            <option value="multiplication"> Multiplication </option>
                            <option value="division"> Division </option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="calculate">
                    </form> 
                </body>
            </html>
HTML;
    }
?>
```

Is it just not doing process_form() or is it resetting the value of calculate when pressing the button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch `$_POST['operation']`.

Most of vulnerabilities on websites are from saving data to databases, presenting other users data to users. Code like that does not seem to have any security problems, but `echo` seems to be more popular than `print` for outputting data.

Answer (score 0):

In your switch statement you should change `switch($_POST)` to `switch($_POST['operation'])`.

As i can see you are matching select tag with name *operation* and then you do the math.

So, if you want to get the correct value of select tag then you must use `$_POST['operation']`

Answer (score 0):

In function call, Pass the post data and define your function with parameter or argument as below

```
if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){
        process_form($_POST['calculate']);
    } 
function process_form($arg){
    switch($arg){
        case "addition":
            print $_POST['operand1'] + $_POST['operand2'];
            break;
        case "subtraction":

            break;
        case "multiplication":

            break;
        case "division":

    }
```